# Getting multiple value from another column for a single column type

Tags: php, json

I want to retrieve more than one `offer_title`, offer price etc for a single store value but only one offer is returning. There is more than one store offer for a particular store in the database. How to do so?

Here is my code:

```
<?php 

$sql ="SELECT * , Offer_Master.Store_id 
        FROM Store_Master_Profile 
            INNER JOIN Offer_Master 
                ON Store_Master_Profile.Store_Name = Offer_Master.Store_id 
                AND Store_Master_Profile.tag like '%Electronics%' 
        LIMIT 0 , 300 ";

require_once('Config.php');

$r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$result = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){
    array_push($result,array(
                    'storephoto'=>$row['storephoto'],
                    'Store_Name'=>$row['Store_Name'],
                    'Store_email'=>$row['email'],
                    'City_id'=>$row['City_id'],
                    'Area_id'=>$row['Area_id'],
                    'Address'=>$row['Address'],
                    'Latitude'=>$row['Latitude'],
                    'Longitude'=>$row['Longitude'],
                    'mobile'=>$row['mobile'],
                    'Store_Feature'=>$row['Store_Feature'],
                    'tag'=>$row['tag'],
                    'storeimages'=>$row['storeimages'],
                    'workingdays'=>$row['workingdays'],
                    'fromtime'=>$row['fromtime'],
                    'totime'=>$row['totime'] ,
                    'Offer_Title'=>$row['Offer_Title'],
                    'MRP_Price'=>$row['MRP_Price'],
                    'Actual_Price'=>$row['Actual_Price'],
                    'Description'=>$row['Description'],
                    'Expiry_Date'=>$row['Expiry_Date']  
                    )
            );

}

echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));

mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: Are you sure your query is returning more than one row. That code looks like it should work!

Comment: _Info:_ You could make the code easier to read by changing your while loop to `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){ $result[] = $row; }`

Comment: yes,actually offer_title has data in two row bt i am getting only one row...
is there any way that i can get offer_title,mrp_price,actual_price in a nested array...?because for a particular store,it can have more than one offer

Comment: Run the query in phpMyAdmin or something similiar and see how many rows are returned

Comment: only one row for Offer_Master table...Is there any way that i can put offer_title,mrp_price in a array that will be inside result array?